# NetLogo - Stepping on patch initializes new function

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I'm creating this game on Netlogo where a turtle basically moves through a maze to the red patch. Once at the red patch it will go onto the next level. I have written both maps but how do I connect the two?

How do I make it so when a turtle steps on a red patch a new function initializes?

Comment: How are you distributing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ask turtle-in-question [if pcolor = red [code you want to run] ]
```

Should work
 as does

```
if [pcolor] of turtle-in-question = red [code to make new level]
```

it works at the observer level so in most cases it will be the better choice.

Comment: Or if you want it from the observer context rather than the turtle context, then, in the go procedure, something like `if [pcolor] of turtle-in-question [name-of-fuction]`

Comment: @JenB: you mean `if [pcolor = red] of ...` or `if [pcolor] of turtle-in-question = red` (both are valid)

Comment: Should I add those to the answer for completeness ... yes okay I will